# Where does Spring Cloud AWS 2.x auto-configure the AmazonS3 bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

I'm currently running into the [well-known startup failure](https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-cloud-aws/issues/148#issuecomment-218163733) where Spring Cloud AWS is attempting to create an `AmazonS3` bean but doesn't have a region defined. In a particular profile, I do not want Spring Cloud AWS to activate *anything at all*. I have successfully suppressed SNS and SQS with `cloud.aws.{sns,sqs}.enabled=false`, but I can't find where the `AmazonWebserviceClientFactoryBean<AmazonS3>` is injected into the context; debugging the constructor shows it's being lazily created from a bean definition.

What code in Spring Cloud AWS auto-configures the bean for the `AmazonS3` client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ContextResourceLoaderAutoConfiguration` class indirectly imports `ContextResourceLoaderConfiguration.Registrar`, which has a hard-coded bean registration for an `AmazonS3Client` buried inside it. Neither the registrar nor the auto-configuration class supports the usual well-behaved property conditions to disable S3 client creation (e.g., `cloud.aws.{s3,loader}.enabled=false`).

In order to suppress creation of the S3 client (which is unconditional), the `ContextResourceLoaderAutoConfiguration` class must be listed in the `exclude` parameter of the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` or `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.